# REST End Point Still Showing Old Alias of Updated Field After Publishing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

Using ArcGIS 10.6 and ArcGIS Server 10.6. I have changed the Alias of a Feature Class to ObjectID like

[image]

and it is showing in the attribute table like

[image]

(After Saving and even re-booting the MXD) but when I publish the map as Map Service the output still showing old alias (FID)  in the Service REST end point!

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try clearing the browser cache?

Comment: Thanks for comment Kirk, well as I said I published a new service so there was nothing old on browser cache, I actually did crating browser data after your comment and the alias still showing old on MXD

Comment: What happens if you right click on the layer in the TOC, choose "Properties..." then on the Fields tab change the Alias under the Appearance section in the right panel, save and then publish?